# Spring - No acceptable representation with AWS S3AsyncClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, spring-async, aws-s3-client

I am trying to download a file from S3 using S3AsyncClient's `getObject(objectRequest, AsyncResponseTransformer.toBlockingInputStream())` which returns a `CompletableFuture<ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>>` in my controller. But it throws below the exception.

Exception Message:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:322)
```

**Controller**

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseInputStream;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/vone/sthreedownload")
public class S3Controller {
    private S3Service s3service;
    public S3Controller(S3Service s3service) {
        this.s3service = s3service;
    }
    @GetMapping(value="/download-file/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE )
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>> downloadFileFromS3(String id){
        return s3service.downLoadFile(id);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class S3Service {
    
    private S3AsyncClient s3CAsyncClient;

    public S3Service(S3AsyncClient s3cAsyncClient) {
        s3CAsyncClient = s3cAsyncClient;
    }
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>> downLoadFile(String id) {
        GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder().key(id).bucket("BCD").build();
        return s3CAsyncClient.getObject(objectRequest, AsyncResponseTransformer.toBlockingInputStream());

    }

}
```